# Modify list item field using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, splistitem, xml, splist

I have a list field that stores an `XML` string.

I am trying to get the `XML` contents and modify a particular tag in the `XML` like so:

```
foreach($item in $list.Items)
{
    if($item["XMLField"].Contains("NodeImLookingFor"))
    {
        $itemNum = $item["ID"]
        Write-Host ("{0} - {1}" -f $s, $itemNum)
        $a = $item["XMLField"]
        $a = $a.Replace("NodeImLookingFor", "ReplacementNode")
        $item["XMLField"] = $a
        $item.Update()
    }
}
```

The script above, however, deletes the contents in that field. Frustrated, I started over and repopulated the field with the `XML`. Once repopulated I tried the following:

```
foreach($item in $list.Items)
{
    if($item["XMLField"].Contains("NodeImLookingFor"))
    {
        Write-Host $item["XMLField"] #Displays the XML content in the cmd window
        $a = $item["XMLField"]
        Write-Host $a   #Does not display anything
    }
}
```

Now i'm confused should I just run the `replace` command straight on `$item["XMLField"]` instead of sticking its contents into the `$a` variable and editing it from there. My concern is I will delete the list field contents regardless. Please advise.

Answer (score 1):

There is an XML type in PowerShell. [Exploring XML Document by Using the [XML] Type Accelerator](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2014/06/10/exploring-xml-document-by-using-the-xml-type-accelerator.aspx)

Define $a as

```
[XML]$a = $item["XMLField"];
```

Now you would be able to lookup set the value of NodeImLookingFor as

```
$a.NodeImLookingFor = "New Value";
```

Regards

Comment: Thanks! But I am not trying to actually find and modify the value for `NoteImLookingFor` i'm trying to modify the name of the node itself. How do I do that?